# UITableViewController through Modal Toolbar button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I have a `TableViewController` named Holidays it is set in storyboard as *dynamic properties* with two cells: one to display the value, and another to display a date picker. In the storyboard, if I set HolidaysController as my root view and run, it works fine, displays value and picker in the way I set it to. But if I instead from another viewcontroller call `HolidayViewController` in this way:

```
- (void)holidayActionPressed:(id)sender{
    HolidayViewController *controller = [[HolidayViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It does not work. It can't find my cells; they return nil. How should I initialize `HolidayViewController` in order to work when being called from my other view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to instantiate HolidayViewController with this :

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle: nil];
HolidayViewController *controller = (HolidayViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"HolidayIdentifier"];
```

When HolidayIdentifier must be set in storyboard